# How to capture data change in SQL Server table using triggers when we are refreshing an entire table instead of some records?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, dml, change-tracking

I have an `Inventory` table in a staging database which gets refreshed every day. I have created a job that drops the table first and then insert whole table from transactional DB to the staging DB. I want to capture all records changed in one day.

Question: is there a way to capture changed values since the last refresh using DML triggers? (I know DML triggers work on `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` operations on records, but here I am dropping the entire table and reinserting data into it from Oracle OLTP DB). Change data capture(CDC) functionality is not supported in my SQL Server Business Intelligence edition.

Comment: Since you're not actually **updating** existing rows, but simply **inserting** everything again - you could have an `INSERT` trigger, but that would just simply list of **all** the rows inserted again. If you want to **compare** with the previous state, you'll have to someone preserve the previous state (not drop the whole table), do the insert, and compare.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for your reply. But, how I can preserve  the previous state of the  table and then compare it with today's updated table ? I can run a trigger on Production table which refreshes every second but It might cause performance issue.

Comment: One strategy might to be *rename* the existing table (instead of truncating it), creating a new copy of the table under the original name, and then load the data into that newly created (and thus empty) table. Now you have the **old**; renamed table with yesterday's data, and today's data in the newly created table - now you can compare quite easily ...